# Sorting an unordered list with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an unordered list.

This list has elements with checkboxes in it. If you check in a checkbox, the list element goes to the bottom of the list. when you check out one of the checkboxes, it has to go back to its original place. so far, I managed.

BUT. Take the following situation: You checked in all the checkboxes, and they seem to align according to their original place. Now, when you check out a list element, it will stuck between to other elements, which are on their place, but they are checked in. I want that in that case, the checked off box will be the first in the list. Then, when you check off the next box, that one will now be on the right place, aligning with thee unchecked boxes only.

TL;DR:

I have to make a To Do list, the 'done' elements go to the bottom, the undone elements sorted above, according to their timestamp.

http://codepen.io/balazsorban44/pen/mAvqmk

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Todo List</title>
    <style media="screen">
      *{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: gold;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: 1em;
        border: none;
      }
      body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background: #333;
      }
      #content{
        border: 1px solid #333;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: gold;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      }
      h1,h2{
        display: block;
        color: #444;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        padding: 10px;
        align-self: flex-start;
      }
      h2{
        font-size: 1.1em
      }
      input{
        color: #333;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #333;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)
      }
      input:focus{
        outline: none
      }
      button{
        background: #333;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        max-width: 50%;
        margin-top:15px;
        cursor: pointer
      }
      ul li{
        list-style-type: none;
        color:#333;
        min-width: 100px;
        padding: 5px;
        align-self: flex-start;
      }
      ul li input{
        margin: 0 5px
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="loaded()">
    <div id=content>
      <h1>A very nice To Do list</h1>
      <div>
        <input id="todo-input" type="text" name="todo-input" value="" placeholder="Click + or press Enter." onkeydown="enter()">
        <button type="button" name="button" onclick="addTask()">+</button>
      </div>
      <h2>Your todo list (done/all): <output>/</output></h2> 
      <ul id="tasks">

      </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const inputArea= document.getElementById('todo-input')
    const list = document.getElementById("tasks");
    tasks = [];


    function loaded(){
      inputArea.focus();
    }

    function addTask(){
      const newTask = document.createElement("li")
      const text = document.createTextNode(inputArea.value)
      const checkBox = document.createElement("input");

      newTask.appendChild(text);
      list.insertBefore(newTask, list.childNodes[0]);
      checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
      checkBox.setAttribute("onclick", "toggleCheckBox()");
      list.childNodes[0].insertBefore(checkBox, list.childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);
      tasks.push({timestamp: new Date(), task: inputArea.value});
      list.childNodes[0].id=tasks[tasks.length-1].timestamp.getTime();
      inputArea.value ="";
      inputArea.focus();
    }

    function enter(){
      if(event.keyCode == 13) {
          addTask()
        }
    }

    function toggleCheckBox(){
      const task = event.target.parentNode
      if (task.style.textDecoration == '') {
        task.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        list.appendChild(task)
      }
      else {
        task.style.textDecoration = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
          if (task.id > list.childNodes[i].id) {
            list.insertBefore(task, list.childNodes[i]);
            break
          }
        }
      }
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is your question? Specifically, what issues are you encountering in implementing this?

Comment: I don't know how to make it go to the top of the list, when the special alignment occurs.

Comment: You can easily make a to-do list with angularjs or some other template library. I think the easiest way to manage your structure is creating an array of tasks and update the html accordingly.

Comment: I have to use plain JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Manage your `tasks` list in javascript and update the HTML whenever a checkbox value is changed or task is added:

```
var inputArea = document.getElementById('todo-input')
var list = document.getElementById("tasks");
var tasks = [];

function loaded() {
  inputArea.value = "";
  inputArea.focus();
}

function update(){
  list.innerHTML = '';
  // Sort the tasks on done boolean
  tasks.sort(function(x, y) {
    return (x.done === y.done)? 0 : x.done ? 1 : -1;
  });

  for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++){
    var item = tasks[i];
    var task = document.createElement("li")
    var text = document.createElement("span");
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    text.innerHTML = item.task;
    text.style.color = 'black';
    checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    checkBox.addEventListener("change", (function(t){
      return function(){
        tasks[t].done = this.checked;
        console.log(tasks[t]);
        update();
      }
    }(i)));
    if(item.done){
      checkBox.checked = true;
      text.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
    }
    task.appendChild(checkBox);
    task.appendChild(text);
    list.appendChild(task);
  }
}

function addTask() {
  tasks.push({
    id: tasks.length ? tasks[tasks.length - 1].timestamp.getTime() : +new Date(),
    done: false,
    timestamp: new Date(),
    task: inputArea.value
  });
  update();
  loaded();
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EgAbdZ)

Comment: It does not work for me! Actually, it breaks my code even more. But thanks for trying.

Comment: @BalázsOrbán Did you see the codepen? What does it break?

Comment: I saw, yes. Just check for example with 1,2,3 as list elements. check all of them, then they will be on the same place as before. Now, when you check them off again, they won't jump where I wanted to.

Comment: @BalázsOrbán On my screen the Done checkboxes move to the bottom of the list. If I uncheck them they will move up again.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to make an object structure as

```
function Task(id,itemName,timeStamp,isCompleted){
   this.id=id;
   this.itemName=itemName;
   this.time=timeStamp;
   this.completed=isCompleted;

}
var Tasks=[];
```

while adding each task,you have to save in such format.
So whenever a task is completed ,you would set completed to true . For all the uncompleted tasks all you need to do is to sort based on their time or based on their name

Hope this helps

Comment: I dont understand why there is a downvote here,but maintaining your tasks in an array format of this structure would give you a better maintainability and sorting would be easier too...,are u looking for how to move the tasks up in the ui?you did not mention this in the question